# Kivy (Python) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy and I am trying to make an App that count words in a string and display the number of words on a new popup , And I keep getting this error message even with using str() . Type-error: expected string or buffer
Here is the code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import re


class CountRoot(BoxLayout):
    def clk(self, text_input):

        text = Label(text="Hello, {}!".format(text_input))
        res = re.findall("(\S+)", text)
        nw = Popup(title="Our Title!", content=res,size_hint=(.7, .7))
        nw.open()


class CountApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CountRoot()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     CountApp().run()
```

Here is the kivy file :

```
<CountRoot>:
orientation: "vertical"
padding: root.width * .02, root.height * .02
spacing: "10dp"


TextInput:
    id: text_input
    hint_text: "Enter Text"
    font_size: "30dp"

Button:
    text: "Press Me"
    on_release: root.clk(text_input.text)
```

Comment: The error message tells you which line the error is on.

Comment: What is `res`? Is it a string? Are you sure? Have you checked? The [documentation says it's a list of strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: res is the result of ''re.findall("(\S+)", text)'' and it is a number ( int )

Comment: Should you be passing an `int` to `content`?

Comment: Yes , res( the number ) should be displayed on that popup

Comment: So which line is the error on?

Comment: nw = Popup(title="Our Title!", content=res,size_hint=(.7, .7))

Comment: If you replace `content=res` with `content=type(res)`, what happens?

Comment: What's the full and exact error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what You want to achieve (as the code says something different than the description), but either way You were assigning Label widget as the *text* string opposed to label content itself (as Jaques said).

One more thing to remember: popup *content* accepts **one widget** (I'm passing Label with answer below)

So You can do:

KV:

```
...
    Button:
        text: "Press Me"
        on_release: root.clk(text_input.text)
```

py:

```
class CountRoot(BoxLayout):
    def clk(self, text_input):
        res = re.findall("(\S+)", text_input)
        nw = Popup(title="Our Title!", content=Label(text='No of words: ' + str(len(res))))
        nw.open()
```

**or** (reffering dirrectly to kivy's root widget ids dictionary):

KV:

```
...

Button:
    text: "Press Me"
    on_release: root.clk()
```

py:

```
class CountRoot(BoxLayout):
    def clk(self):
        text = self.ids.text_input.text
        res = re.findall("(\S+)", text)
        nw = Popup(title="Our Title!", content=Label(text='No of words: ' + str(len(res))))
        nw.open()
```

Comment: The first solution worked!!! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

In

```
text = Label(text="Hello, {}!".format(text_input))
```

variable text that is assigned to, is a Label object rather than a string. There's no regex search possible on such an object. Use it on  a string instead.

Comment: This is why i could not tell where is the problem

Comment: So search the contents of your label, rather than the label itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11890407)

Comment: @cpburnz This is the correct answer. OP hasn't told us which line the error is on.

Comment: @PeterWood This answer reads more like a comment to me. It looks correct, but it doesn't provide a solution.

Comment: Edited to be more explicit.